# Prove that if $x$ is odd, then $x^2$ is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Prove that if $x$ is odd, then $x^2$ is odd

Suppose $x$ is odd. Dividing $x^2$ by 2, we get:
$$\frac{x^2}{2} = x \cdot \frac{x}{2}$$
$\frac{x}{2}$ can be rewritten as $\frac{x}{2} = a + 0.5$ where $a \in \mathbb Z$. Now, $x\cdot\frac{x}{2}$ can be rewritten as:

$$x\cdot\frac{x}{2} = x(a+0.5) = xa + \frac{x}{2}$$

$xa \in \mathbb Z$ and $\frac{x}{2} \notin \mathbb Z$, hence $xa + \frac{x}{2}$ is not a integer. And since $xa + \frac{x}{2} = \frac{x^2}{2}$, it follows that $x^2$ is not divisible by two, and thus $x^2$ is odd.

Is it correct?

Comment: If you are saying $x=2a+1$ for some integer $a$ then an easier approach may be to say $x^2= 2(2a^2+2a)+1$ which is $1$ more than an even number and so odd.

Comment: odd times odd is odd

Comment: proof by contrapositive:  if $x^2$ is even, then $2|x^2,$ so $2|x$ (by Euclid's lemma), so $x$ is even

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct. Good job!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your written proof is correct. FYI, here is another proof technique which, although it's far more than you need in your case as Bill's comment indicates, is somewhat shorter and, perhaps, of some use to you, such as for other more complicated related problems.

Since $x$ is odd, this means it has no factors of $2$. By the [Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), $x^2$ has the same prime factors as $x$, just twice as many of each of them and, thus, also no factor of $2$. As such, it is also odd.

Comment: @OP while that's worth knowing, one should be aware that using FTA here is like using a sledgehammer to crack open a nut. Much less powerful methods suffice (e.g. parity arguments).

Answer (score 10):

Let $x = 2k + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ be odd. So, $$ x^{2} = (2k + 1)^2 = 4k^{2} + 4k + 1 = 2(2k^{2} + 2k) + 1$$ Let $t = 2k^{2} + 2k  \in \mathbb{Z}$, thus: $ x^{2} = 2t + 1$.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @SantanaAfton The only thing missing is “and $2t+1$ must be odd” which is understood if you followed the proof from the beginning since it starts with understanding $2k+1$ is odd.

Comment: @let'shaveabreakdown This is an answer to “Prove that if $x$ is odd then $x^2$ is odd” which is not the question. The OP has given this the proof-verification tag, and asked “is [the proof in the question] correct?” This answer does not address that question.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct.

You could also prove by contrapositive:

if $x^2$ is even, then $2|x^2=x\cdot x,$ so by [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) $2|x,$ so $x$ is even.

If you don't like that, you could say $x$ is odd, and the product of two odd numbers is odd,

so $x^2=x\cdot x$ is odd.

If you don't like that, you could argue as follows:

if $x$ is odd, then $x-1=2k$ and $x+1=2k+2$ with $k \in\Bbb Z$,

so $x^2=(x-1)(x+1)+1=(2k)(2k+2)+1=2(k(2k+2))+1$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $ $ your proof is correct. $ $ You have $\ a = \color{#c00}{(x\!-\!1)/2}\in\Bbb Z\ $ so eliminating $\,a\,$ the proof becomes

$$\begin{align} &\dfrac{x^2}2 - \dfrac{x}2\, =\, \dfrac{x(\color{#c00}{x\!-\!1})}{\color{#c00}2}\in \Bbb Z\\[.2em]
\Rightarrow\ \ \ &\dfrac{x^2}2\in\Bbb Z\iff \dfrac{x}2\in\Bbb Z\\[.2em]
\Rightarrow\ \ \ & \ \ \ \ 2\nmid {x^2}\iff\ \  2\nmid x\\[.2em]
{\rm i.e.}\  \ \ & \ x^2\  {\rm odd}\ \iff x\ \  {\rm odd}
\end{align}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$